# snapでdockerをインストールした場合、ホームディレクトリ配下以外だとdocker-composeがdocker-compose.ymlを見つけられない

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

OS: ubuntu18.04LTS

snapでdockerをインストールした場合、ルートディレクトリ配下にディレクトリを作り、docker-compose.ymlを配置後に、docker-compose upをしても、下記エラーで実行できません。
ホームディレクトリ配下のディレクトリでは、きちんと実行できます。
原因、解決策をご存知の方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか。

```
ERROR: 
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

具体的には、それぞれのhogeディレクトリでdocker-compose.ymlが置いてある前提で、下記では上記エラーが出ますが、

```
$ sudo mdkir /hoge
$ cd /hoge
$ sudo docker-compose up
```

下記では実行できます。

```
$ mkdir ~/hoge
$ cd ~/hoge
$ sudo docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 1):

同様の事象がこちらで報告されています:

- ["Can't find a suitable configuration file" on Ubuntu 18.04.1](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6361) - docker/compose issues  #6361

対処法としては、snapでインストールされているdocker-composeを利用せず、別途[マニュアルインストール](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose)してそれを使うことが挙げられています。

Comment: +1: 関連? [How to give snaps access to /somedir](https://askubuntu.com/q/1033344/644471) -- AskUbuntu, [snap apps need to be able to browse outside of user $HOME dir. for Desktop installs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1643706) -- bugs.launchpad.net

Answer (score 0):

2つ目の手順ですが、

```
$ mkdir ~/hoge
$ cd /hoge
```

ここがおかしいような気がします。ディレクトリが違うので参照するものが違うような・・・

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ここのcdはcd ~/hogeです。。。ls でdocker-compose.ymlの存在は確認しています。せっかく回答いただいたのにすいません。。。

Comment: もとの質問も直しておくと良さそうです！ @Yuya

Comment: その通りですね！ご指摘ありがとうございます。